# Postgres JSONB date condition true for all entries of an array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB that looks something like this

```
[{
"foo":"bar",
"date":"2020-01-01"
},
{
"foo":"bar",
"date":"2020-02-03"
},
{
"foo":"bar",
"date":"2020-01-02"
}]
```

I need a query to return true if ALL of the "date"s are less than 1 year ago. I have looked at the [postgres JBON documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) and the only thing sort of fitting I found was using ?& but I'm not just trying to compare strings but dates that are strings so I am kind of lost here

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate over all elements and then convert the strings to dates in order to be able to compare them.

```
select .... other columns ...., 
       current_date - interval '1 year' < all (select (x.entry ->> 'date')::date
                                               from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as x(entry))
from the_table t
```

Comment: That gives me the error `cannot extract elements from an object`

Comment: Then apparently your JSON doesn't contain an array - contrary to what you wrote in your question https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f78ac8ea2cc6d963a2f64cd1a766b84

Comment: you're right, there are some entries in my DB where there's no data so its just `{}`, guess I'll need to filter those out